# Encoding special chars in XSLT output

Tags: unicode, vbscript

I have built a set of scripts, part of which transform XML documents from one vocabulary to a subset of the document in another vocabulary.

For reasons that are opaque to me, but apparently non-negotiable, the target platform (Java-based) requires the output document to have 'encoding="UTF-8"' in the XML declaration, but some special characters within text nodes must be encoded with their hex unicode value - e.g. '”' must be replaced with '`&#x201D;`' and so forth. I have not been able to acquire a definitive list of which chars must be encoded, but it does not appear to be as simple as "all non-ASCII".

Currently, I have a horrid mess of VBScript using ADODB to directly check each line of the output file after processing, and replace characters where necessary. This is painfully slow, and unsurprisingly some characters get missed (and are consequently nuked by the target platform).

While I could waste time "refining" the VBScript, the long-term aim is to get rid of that entirely, and I'm sure there must be a faster and more accurate way of achieving this, ideally within the XSLT stage itself.

Can anyone suggest any fruitful avenues of investigation?

(edit: I'm not convinced that character maps are the answer - I've looked at them before, and unless I'm mistaken, since my input could conceivably contain *any* unicode character, I would need to have a map containing all of them *except* the ones I don't want encoded...)

Answer (score 3):

```
<xsl:output encoding="us-ascii"/>
```

Tells the serialiser that it has to produce ASCII-compatible output. That should force it to produce character references for all non-ASCII characters in text content and attribute values. (Should there be non-ASCII in other places like tag or attribute names, serialisation will fail.)

Answer (score 0):

Well with XSLT 2.0 you have tagged your post with you can use a character map, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#character-maps.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not convinced about character maps - I've looked at them (will edit my post to mention this) before, and unless I'm mistaken, since my input could conceivably contain *any* unicode character, I would need to have a map containing all of them *except* the ones I don't want encoded...

Comment: It is true that a character map needs to list the characters you want to encode but if you currently have a VBScript doing that task then I don't see why you can't set up a character map instead. Or how does your current algorithm look to decide whether to encode or not to encode a character?

Comment: At the moment, I check each char against a regex matching my best (albeit somewhat informed!) guess as to which characters *shouldn't* be encoded, and then encode if there's no match.

Comment: Hm, that sounds as if character maps don't help. And the whole description is kind of vague and as far as I am aware the Java platform with Xerces has XML parsers fully supporting Unicode and UTF-8 so I don't know what to suggest other than avoiding the problem by using an XML parser that does what any XML parser is supposed to do, namely supporting Unicode.

Comment: I'm afraid I only have vague knowledge of the target platform (but that's another story entirely...). You're quite right that what you suggest would avoid the problem completely, but as far as I can gather, that system doesn't do any XML parsing, and instead treats the XML documents that it requires as plain text. Changes to that system seem to be completely off the table, sadly.